# How to Use Voice Commands or Speech to enter message text in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

In Windows Phone I have a message text box, and I want to enter a message based on event like Birthday, Reminder or any events like Festivals or Anniversary etc.
I want to have a voice command or a speech recognizer which would allow the Users to enter their message in the message text box through this voice command or speech recognition and send to other person via SMS etc.
In windows there is already a launcher available SMSComposeTask which has this voice option I guess but I want this funcitonality in my App.
Any help or useful links or snippets on the same?.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
[Speech recognition for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207021%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
[Speech-Enabling a Windows Phone 8 App with Voice Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj721592.aspx)
or the samples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206958(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Hey thanks for the links. I checked the predefined dictation grammar code: 
var recognizerWithUI = new SpeechRecognizerUI(); SpeechRecognitionUIResult recognizerResult = await recognizerWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
MessageBox.Show(string.Format(“I heard {0}.”, recognizerResult.RecognitionResult.Text)); 

So just writing this code would help me or should I need to define a SpeechRecognizer object for adding grammars from predefined type.